# Regex not working with PHP + cURL

Tags: php, regex, curl

I'm making a cURL request to take data from one page. 
The returned HTML content is (view image below):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/owKjr.png

I want to filter the following content 'Saldo principal: R$ 27,50'.
I'm trying to do this with regular expression but the script is returning an empty array.

This is my code:

```
$content = getContent();
preg_match_all("/Saldo Principal: R\$ [0-9]{1,},[0-9]{1,}/i", $content, $result);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

This is the result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )
```

I tested this using a regular expression site and everything is ok. Why is not working with PHP?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/64pyJ.png

Comment: `preg_match_all("/Saldo Principal: R\\$ [0-9]{1,},[0-9]{1,}/i", $content, $result);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) Class.

```
$content = getContent();
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $tag) {
       $pcontent[]=$tag->nodeValue;
}
echo trim($pcontent[1]); //"prints" Saldo principal: R$ 27,50
```

or you could put it in a single line. Like this.

```
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(1)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a double quoted string the backslash is treated as an escape character. thus:

either you single quote:

`preg_match_all('/Saldo Principal: R\$ [0-9]{1,},[0-9]{1,}/i', $content, $result);`

or double escape:

`preg_match_all("/Saldo Principal: R\\$ [0-9]{1,},[0-9]{1,}/i", $content, $result);`